# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Tags: python, json

Получаю строку с сайта, которая в дальнейшем загружается в json. Но в строке есть название монитора с указанием диагонали в виде двойных кавычек, в следствии возникает исключение.
Есть и похожие строки, которые обрабатываются в except, когда в except указан индекс значения, из за которого ошибка.
Так вот, строка вида
`{"adv_second_bid":"sVllSaddaf","adv_second_bid_2":"fgfdgdfgfdg","availability":1,"availableDeliverySchema":[221],"brand":"name brand","brandId":1002200,"countItems":60,"deliveryTimeDiffDays":7,"discount":31,"finalPrice":1111,"id":1212222,"index":1,"isRfbs":false,"labels":[{"names":["directDiscount"]},{"names":["bestseller"]},{"names":null}],"link":"link","marketingActionIds":[123123],"price":123213,"product_type":"product","quantity":1,"rating":4.616666793823242,"sellerId":1321321,"stockCount":5,"tileType":1,"title":"19" Моноблок Alfa computers"}`.
Тут понятно, что после 19 кавычка лишняя, но в except почему то пишет на 1 индекс, хотя это далеко за 1000 индекс элемента.
Может кто сталкивался с таким?

Comment: "title":"19" описание... "} или все таки {"title":"19" описание... "}?

Comment: Да, верно, исправил. Добавил строку как есть, заменив значения.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал `replace('\\"', '\"')` по всем строке и все получилось.
Что странно, почему не мог разобраться, оказывается если с debagger`a копировать значение этой строки, то при вставке дубликаты обратных слеш чудом удаляются, по этому и у меня возникали трудности в понимании, что вообще происходит..)